# Remove duplicate from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a very simple array that has duplicate values. My array is like this:

```
$scope.type= ["Bar", "Pie", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "map", "Line", "Bar", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie"]
```

in my ng-repeat, I have this condition

```
ng-repeat = types in type track by $index
```

How can I display only the unique values from my array in ng-repeat?

Comment: is this really a duplicate? this question is about an angularjs filter but the suggested duplicate is about a pure JavaScript array. Yes, helpful a JavaScript question will not provide an angularjs filter as its answer. I have just used the A below and its worked very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `unique` filter while using `ng-repeat`.

```
ng-repeat="type in types|unique: type"
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.directives', 'ui.filters']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.types = ["Bar", "Pie", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "map", "Line", "Bar", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="type in types|unique: type">{{type}}</div>
</body>
```

Comment: ng-repeat="type in charttype track by $index " My ng-repeat has track by

Comment: If you use `track by $index` then `unique` won't work.

Comment: ok, I used unique and its working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to include Lodash, you can do this:

```
$scope.typeUnique = Object.keys($scope.type.reduce((acc, val) => { acc[val] = true; return acc; }, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash for convert your array to unque element array

```
$scope.type = _.uniq($scope.type);
```

To use loadsh you need to use cdn for lodash

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#uniq

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop :

```
$scope.type= ["Bar", "Pie", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "map", "Line", "Bar", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie"];

var output = [];


angular.forEach($scope.type, function(type, index) {

          // if it's not already part of our keys array
          if(output.indexOf(type) === -1) {
              // push this item to our final output array
              output.push(item);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result first sort and then filter with ng-if

```
      <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in sortedType = (type | orderBy) track by $index" ng-if="sortedType[$index -1] != x">
        {{ x }}
      </li>
    </ul>
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bvVMvV

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type= ["Bar", "Pie", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "Line", "map", "Line", "Bar", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie", "Pie"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">
  
  <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="x in sortedType = (type | orderBy) track by $index" ng-if="sortedType[$index -1] != x">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
</body>
```