# Display the value only if the current value in the loop is not same as the previous value in jsp using ng- repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-repeat in my jsp to loop and display the values.if i have the value more then one time in the list i need to display only once.

Display the value only if the  current value in the loop is not same as the previous value in jsp using ng- repeat

please find my code:

```
           <td> 
            // obj.vm is name. name should be displayed only if it is diferrent then the previous name. otherwise it should be blank 
            <div  obj.vm> </div>
            </td>

           // obj.dm is value. all the values should be displayed 
           <td>  <div obj.dm>  </div>
           </td>
           </tr>
```

---

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in selItem.surveyRefData">
  <td nowrap> // need to display ob.vm only if the current value is not same as previous value 
    <div style="float: left;" class="form-actions" obj.vm"> 
    </div> 
  </td> 
  <td> 
    <div style="float: left;" class="form-actions"
         ng-bind-html="(!validSeriesIdReqPending ?(obj.dm | seriesText):'')"> 
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
```

---

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in selItem.surveyRefData|unique: obj"> 
  <td> // obj.vm is name. name should be displayed only if it is diferrent then the previous name. otherwise it should be blank 
    <div obj.vm> 
    </div> </td> // obj.dm is value. all the values should be displayed 
  <td> 
    <div obj.dm> </div> 
  </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: my code :  <tr  ng-repeat="obj in selItem.surveyRefData">
                                  
      <td nowrap> 
 // need to display ob.vm only if the current value is not same as previous value
      <div  style="float: left;" class="form-actions" obj.vm"> 
      </div>
           
      </td>
      
      <td> 
      <div  style="float: left;" class="form-actions"  ng-bind-html="(!validSeriesIdReqPending ?(obj.dm | seriesText):'')"> 
      </div><br/><br/>

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include to code in the body :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247681/remove-duplicate-from-ng-repeat   This will solve your issue.

Comment: i have modified the code like below:  <tr  ng-repeat="obj in selItem.surveyRefData|unique: obj">

Comment: But it is not working. it is displaying all the records. my obj has 2 columns like name and value. value should be displayed always. but name should be displayed only if the current name is different then the previous name

Comment: Please find my code:  <tr  ng-repeat="obj in selItem.surveyRefData|unique: obj">
                                  
      <td> 
       // obj.vm is name. name should be displayed only if it is diferrent then the previous name. otherwise it should be blank 
       <div  obj.vm> </div>
       </td>
      
      // obj.dm is value. all the values should be displayed 
      <td>  <div obj.dm>  </div>
      </td>
      </tr>

Comment: create method in controller which will take name as parameter and method will have a list in which it will add the name if it is not present in it already.and return true or false if name is already prseent in list or not. show the name tag in html in ng-if="method(name)" like this.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to preprocess the data and group it by the `vm` attribute, so you would have some structure like this:

```
name1
  value1
  value2
  value3
name2
  value4
  value5
name3
  value5
...
```

Then you would have a nested `ng-repeat` that loops over the values within each name. If, for some reason, you can't preprocess the data, you can refer to the previous item in your `ng-repeat` using the `$index` variable. Here is a simple example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in selItem.surveyRefData">
  <td>{{obj.vm !== selItem.surveyRefData[$index-1].vm ? obj.vm : ''}}</td>
  <td>{{obj.dm}}</td>
</tr>
```

Keep in mind that this will only work if your data is ordered based on the `vm` attribute... if you had `name1 -> name1 -> name2 -> name1`, for example, you would see `name1` twice in your output table.

Here is a simple example plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/r5yxYk4Rr7mXaBeqoJNs